# Problemas na consulta do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```html
<form method="POST" class="w-100" action="pesquisa_diaria.php">
   
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
           
            <div class="col-sm-3"> 
                <label>Tipo de Venda</label>
                   <select class="custom-select" name="tipo_vendas" required>
                     <option value=''>Selecione...</option>
                     <option value='caixa'>Caixa</option>
                     <option value='delivery'>Delivery</option>
                     <option value='null'>Todos</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-3"> 
                <label>Tipo de Pagamento</label>
                   <select class="custom-select" name="tipo_pagamento" required>
                     <option value=''>Selecione...</option>
                     <option value='cartao_credito'>Cartão de Credito</option>
                     <option value='cartao_debito'>Cartão de Debito</option>
                     <option value='dinheiro'>Dinheiro</option>
                     <option value='null'>Todos</option>
                 </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-sm-3"> 
                 <label>Data</label>
                 <input id="datepicker" name="data"  width="276" required/>
            </div>

            <div class="col-12 text-right align-self-end">
                </br><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Pesquisar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Tenho um formulário que faz uma consulta no banco de dados, mas estou com problema nas opções "Todos". Quando seleciono essa opção, a consulta não traz nenhum resultado.

```sql
SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE DATE(date_created) = '2018-12-12'
AND tipo_venda = 'null' AND tipo = 'null' ORDER BY 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que quando você fala `todos` voce quer que ele selecione qualquer valor, se for o caso você precisa fazer algo do tipo:

```
$WHERE = array();
if( $_GET['tipo_pagamento'] != "null" )  // so coloca se nao for null
    array_push($WHERE,"tipo='{$_GET['tipo_pagamento']}'");

if( $_GET['tipo_vendas'] != "null" ) // so coloca se nao for null
    array_push($WHERE,"tipo_venda ='{$_GET['tipo_pagamento']}'");

$WHERE = count($WHERE) ? "AND ".join($WHERE," AND ") : "";

$qry = "SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE DATE(date_created) = '2018-12-12' {$WHERE} ORDER BY 'id'"

print $qry;
```

*O codigo acima não foi testado, mas essa é a ideia*

Comment: Mas to achando também que minha query ta errada porque mesmo jogando o select direto no banco os resultados não vem quando e null,

Comment: Se você quer checar se o valor é `NULL` , tem que usar `IS NULL` - exemplo `tipo_venda  IS NULL`  ou `tipo_venda IS NOT NULL` [MYSQL-doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: A resposta do Icaro está correta. A sua query não vem porque você está comparando 'null' (varchar) com NULL (valor de fato). Se sua tabela possui informações NULL a query deve fazer a comparação "WHERE CAMPO IS NULL" (exemplo) e não "WHERE CAMPO = 'NULL'" (interpretando o valor a ser comparado como varchar). Mas se você está querendo apenas trazer todos sem especificar qual, a resposta está correta.

Comment: to entendo, mas se na minha tabela nao tiver null nos campos, como faço pra trazer tudo

Comment: Nao coloque no `where`. Exemplo quero que venha todos os `tipo_venda` `NULL` ou `NOT NULL`:  `SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE DATE(date_created) = '2018-12-12' AND tipo_pagamento='meu tipo de pagamento' ORDER BY 'id'`

Comment: note que a query nao possui `tipo_venda`, isso porque quero qualquer `tipo_venda`

Comment: agora se voce quiser so os `tipo_venda` com valores **nao nulos**, ai voce coloca `tipo_venda NOT IS NULL`

Comment: vc diz fazer assim SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE DATE(date_created) = '2018-12-12' AND tipo_venda IS NOT NULL AND tipo IS NOT NULL ORDER BY 'id'

Comment: mas se eu escolher outra opção nao daria erro

Comment: isso, essa query vai retornar apenas os registros com algum valor (nao nulo) em `tipo_venda` e `tipo`

Comment: se voce fizer esta outra query `SELECT * FROM vendas WHERE DATE(date_created) = '2018-12-12' ORDER BY 'id'` ele vai pegar todos os registros independente de `tipo_venda` e `tipo`, ou seja eles podem ter valor valido ou nao

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87008/discussion-between-vision-development-and-icaro-martins).